# mysql JOIN has me beat

Tags: php, mysql

From the outset let me say that I really struggle with joins.

I have a table called 'registervendors'. In the table is a column called 'state'. 'state' is a single digit number. I also have a column called 'vendregid'.

I have another table called 'states'. In that table is a column called 'state'. 'state' in this  table is a three letter abbreviation and another called 'statesid' which is a single digit number.

I need all this to happen WHERE  'vendregid' is matched.

So I think it would go something like this:

```
    $rows = $db->select(" SELECT * FROM registervendors r  JOIN states s ON  s.state = r.state WHERE regid='$vendregid' ");
```

if regid is a match I want to pull from table 'states' the abbreviation in column 'state' where table 'statesid' matches 'registorvendors' column 'state' 
Its doing my head in.

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you provide table schema please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read (and you explained) correctly, you want to join the `registervendors` table with the `states` table using the `state` id column on the former and the `statesid` id column on the latter.

```
SELECT rv.*, s.*
FROM registervendors rv
INNER JOIN states s
    ON rv.state = s.statesid
WHERE vendregid = 'some_id'
```

Comment: Well I must have explained it correctly because that works a treat @Tim Biegeleisen  Thank you very much.